# For which type of web database , '0'or'0'='0' works as a password on login page?

Tags: sql, code-injection

How to find vulnerable sites, where one can login using '0'or'0'='0' and such other combinations ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "type of web database" (whatever that might be), but with the way the web application accesses the database.

Comment: It will work for all types if the application doesn't protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asking the question with reference to to **[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. If the login control is using a query based on string concatenation then chances are that this will succeed in logging in.

It should be: `' or '0'='0`